# Space Retention from TextArea in Options Framework Plugin for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the latest version of Options Framework (which is found here:  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/options-framework/) on the latest build of Wordpress to build out some theme options/controls. In a text area, I am asking the user for something that is best output via multiple paragraphs. I want to retain the spacing they specify in this textarea.

I output their option in via shortcode and all spacing is lost. I also output it via an echo and all spacing is lost.  So it seems the spacing loss is occurring between input and storage.

THanks for any help!

Comment: It appears it is related to wp_kses

Comment: I found A solution, though admittedly not the best solution.  It appears that this text replacement is occurring because of two elements.  First, the framework itself sanitizes the textarea input to remove spacing by utilizing wp_kses.  I resolved this by eliminating this function.  Secondly, in storing the input as a shortcode, the spacing was again being stripped out.  I installed another plugin, Exec PHP, which let me call PHP in the post to echo the textarea's input.  But this, admittedly, isn't the best solution.  I have to figure out how to echo that option in an actual post without

Comment: stripping the spacing.  I am thinking that a shortcode creation calls kses too... I think I would be better off fixing the source, which is actually wp_kses... but for all intensive purposes, it looks like wp_kses already allows <br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just tested this locally... the plugin maintains line breaks in the option's textarea, so the problem must be w/ how you are displaying it.

wordpress doesn't **save** p tags in the database, normally so they won't get saved by Devin's plugin.  the function wpautop() is attached to the_content filter and it (sometimes seemingly willy-nilly, but that's a different discussion) determines what should be wrapped in p tags.

what if you

```
echo wpautop(of_get_option('test'));
```

something i came up w/ for a similar issue w/ textareas in metaboxes is to create a filter and attach the normal content filters to that... a "duplicate" the_content if you will.  i started out straight up using apply_filters('the_content' $my_value) but some plugins hook into that filter and it can get weird.

```
echo apply_filters('meta_content',of_get_option('test'));
```

then somewhere in your functions.php

```
//recreate the default filters on the_content
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'wptexturize'        );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'convert_smilies'    );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'convert_chars'      );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'wpautop'            );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'shortcode_unautop'  );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'prepend_attachment' );
```